# How to get the select result as List<Map<String, Object>> in Spring Boot 2.0

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

We are trying to migrate from Spring boot 1.5.x to 2.0.x

**Following is the code used to get select result as List> using Spring boot 1.5.x:**

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> findZipCodeAndCityByState(String state) {
    String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT z.city, z.zip_code FROM zip_code z WHERE z.state = :state";
    Query qr = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
    qr.setParameter("state", state);

    // BELOW LINES WILL GIVE US THE MAP OF PROPERTIES
    org.hibernate.Query hibernateQuery = ((org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateQuery) qr).getHibernateQuery();
    hibernateQuery.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityOrderedMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);

    return qr.getResultList();
}
```

But when we tried to migrate to 2.0.x, got to know that org.hibernate.Query and hibernateQuery.setResultTransformer() both are deprecated.

How to get the select result as List> in Spring Boot 2.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options:

1. Continue using ResultSetTransformer from Hibernate. While some of Hibernate’s features have been deprecated if rougly eauivalent functionality exists in JPA spec, you can easily find a lot of places when using Hibernate API gives you more power ofer JPA. Instead of casting, I suggest calling [unwrap](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#unwrap(java.lang.Class)) on your `Query`
2. Use `List<Tuple>` instead. To use [Tuple](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Tuple.html), you need to use an overloaded version of [createNativeQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-), passing `Tuple.class` as result class
3. Use a DTO projection

A good article summarizing all 3 approaches:
[The best way to map a projection query to a DTO (Data Transfer Object) with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)